# 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a leveling system for my Discord bot and I am working on a "/level" command that displays a user's level or if they input a different user it will show that user's level.

If they input a user it'll show that users level so if they don't input a user I want it to show the author's level, so I have

```
if member is None: member = interaction.message.author
```

but when I use the command it says

```
'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Instead of using

```
interaction: discord.Interaction
```

I used ctx and tried `if member is None: member = ctx.author` I have also tried `ctx.message.author` and I tried `interaction.author`. I have also tried `user` instead of `member`.

I have no idea what to do (I am new to coding.)

Here's my code for the level command.

```
# Level Command | !level {member} | Shows you your current level or the level of another member.
@bot.tree.command(name="level", description="Shows you your current level or the level of another member.")
@app_commands.describe(member="The member who's level you want to see.")
async def level(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = interaction.message.author
    async with bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("SELECT level FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?", (member.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        level = await cursor.fetchone()
        await cursor.execute("SELECT xp FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?", (member.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        xp = await cursor.fetchone()
    
    if not xp or not level:
        await cursor.execute("INSERT INTO levels (levels, xp, user, guild) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (0, 0, member.id, interaction.guild.id,))

    try:
        xp = xp[0]
        level = level [0]
    except TypeError:
        xp = 0
        level = 0
    
    user_data = {
        "xp": xp,
        "level": level,
        "next_level_up": 100,
        "percentage": xp
    }

    background = Editor(Canvas((900, 300), color="#191919"))
    profile_picture = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar.url))
    profile = Editor(profile_picture).resize((150, 150)).circle_image()

    poppins = Font.poppins(size=40)
    poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=40)

    card_right_shape = [(600, 0), (750, 300), (900, 300), (900, 0)]

    background.polygon(card_right_shape, color="#FFFFFF")
    background.paste(profile, (30, 30))

    background.rectangle((30, 220), width=650, height=40, color="#FFFFFF")
    background.bar((30, 220), max_width=650, height=40, percentage=user_data["percentage"], color="#FF0000", radius=20)
    background.text((200, 40), user_data["name"], font=poppins, color="#FFFFFF")

    background.rectangle((200, 100), width=350, height=2, fill="#FFFFFF")
    background.text((200, 130), f"Level - {user_data['level']} | XP - {user_data['xp']}/{user_data['next_level_up']}", font=poppins_small, color="#FFFFFF")

    file = discord.File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="levelcard.png")
    await interaction.response.send_message(file=file)
```

Here's the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    bot.py line 83, in level
    member = interaction.message.author
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

I have tried ctx.author, ctx.message.author, interaction.author, interaction.message.author.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `interaction.message.author`, what do you expect this to mean? In particular, what do you think should be the result of `interaction.message`? Why should it be possible to get a `.author` from that result? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [check](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) this, for example by using `print`?

Comment: On a more conceptual level: If the interaction didn't actually involve sending a message, what member should be used? It can't use the message's author, because there is no message even though there is an interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, as the error says, `interaction.message` has `NoneType`, which you can compare to `undefined` or `nullpointer`. This `interaction.message` is not pointing to a message. You will need to either make sure your function cannot get `NoneType` as argument, or check if `interaction` or `interaction.message` is `NoneType` and handle them seperatly (e.a. if statement)

Hope this helps!